# Chrome Webstore Extension In App Purchase INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store

Partial success with the Chrome InApp purchase flow within a Chrome extension. I have included the buy.js file and implemented the flow as listed on the Chrome walkthrough here:

https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/payments-iap

Using my live extension, I have run through the flow and it works just fine. My credit card is charged and the callback returns successful, I deliver the item. When I check the google.payments.inapp.getPurchases call I can see the item listed as ACTIVE.

However, when I install the production/live extension on any other test computer (a friend's), and try to launch the google.payments.inapp.buy  flow, I get one of two results:

1) A grayed out graphic with the text "In-App Payments is currently unavailable. The transaction could not be completed. Please try again later"

2) A blank window opens, then closes immediately.

The "failure" callback comes back with the error "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR."

Again, the purchase flow works fine on my own Google account, but cannot be completed successfully on any other account. My own internal tracking is showing that 0% of users are completing purchases successfully and this leads me to believe the error is widespread. I know users are trying to make purchases due to internal tracking I have set up, but the only revenue in my Chrome dashboard is from my own test purchases. Something smells funny.

Do any Chrome Webstore Devs have experience with successful in-app payments purchases on live extensions? Help!

Answer (score 1):

I have had successful payments even from other random computers. You may have to check follow for the potential fix:

1. Make sure In-app Items are enabled for all, not just yourself or
   test users
2. Make sure to use 'parameters': {env: "prod"}, wherever you are
   making "google.payments.inapp.*" calls
3. Make sure users are Signed-in their browsers in order to get items,
   licenses and make final purchases successfully
4. Make sure to use the originalId(nmmhkkegccagdldgiimedpiccmgmieda) while calling chrome.runtime.connect() in buy.js, if not then it is the place where it triggers INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am experiencing high failure rates for in-app payments. Users get unexpected errors, but a few purchases do go through. Anyone experiencing something similar? When the payment fails, Chrome is returning just {"request":{},"response":{"errorType":"PURCHASE_CANCELED"}} which is the same you get if you cancel the Buy window.