# Chrome extension in app purchase always returns PURCHASE_CANCELED, even if the purchase worked

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store

This question is related to the one at [Chrome Webstore Extension In App Purchase INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34999782/chrome-webstore-extension-in-app-purchase-internal-server-error). I first posted my question there in the form of a comment, but received feedback that this was more appropriate as a separate question.

Like the OP, I am using buy.js and following the recommended workflow for in-app purchases in the Chrome extension. But my results are somewhat different: when I complete the IAP buy dialog, I get back a PURCHASE_CANCELED, even though I bought the IAP. If I then list the purchases SKUs through the api, it shows up as having been purchased and active. I also get a receipt from the Chrome store.

Does anyone know how to do the IAP buy and get an accurate status message back?

I put together a test extension, and marked it as free with a in-app purchase of "sku1". Here's the relevant code. The entire extension is up at https://github.com/so-codemonkey/testIAP/tree/master.

```
var testiap = (function() {
  return {
    onload: function () {

        var logResults = function( results ) {
                var str = 'Result: ' + JSON.stringify(results);
                console.log(str);
                $('<p>' + str + '</p>').appendTo('#log');
        };

        $(document).on("click","#getskus", function() {
                var str = "getting skus";
                console.log(str);
                $('<p>' + str + '</p>').appendTo('#log');
                google.payments.inapp.getSkuDetails({
                                'parameters': {'env': 'prod'},
                                'success': logResults,
                                'failure': logResults
                                });
        });

        $(document).on("click","#buysku1", function() {
                var str = "buying sku1";
                console.log(str);
                $('<p>' + str + '</p>').appendTo('#log');
                google.payments.inapp.buy({
                                'parameters': {'env': 'prod'},
                                'sku': 'sku1',
                                'success': logResults,
                                'failure': logResults
                                });
        });             

        $(document).on("click","#getpurchases", function() {
                var str = "getting purchased skus";
                console.log(str);
                $('<p>' + str + '</p>').appendTo('#log');
                google.payments.inapp.getPurchases({
                                'parameters': {'env': 'prod'},
                                'success': logResults,
                                'failure': logResults
                                });
        });

        $(document).on("click","#consumesku1", function() {
                var str = "consuming sku1";
                console.log(str);
                $('<p>' + str + '</p>').appendTo('#log');
                google.payments.inapp.consumePurchase({
                                'parameters': {'env': 'prod'},
                                'sku': 'sku1',
                                'success': logResults,
                                'failure': logResults
                                });
        });             

   }
  }
})();
window.onload = testiap.onload;
```

TIA!

Comment: I know this question is older, but I am having the same issue.  The in-app item is purchased but it returns "PURCHASE_CANCELED". But if I close the popup and check google.payments.inapp.getPurchases it shows that the item is purchased. Does anyone have a fix for this?

Comment: My workaround to this problem is to send out a getPurchases api call in the failure handler for the original buy call.