# Chrome extension in-app payment purchase state for cancelled subscription?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

When user successfully purchased the subscription license, the `google.payments.inapp.getPurchases` should return ACTIVE state.

When user cancelled the subscription, which means that the user does not want to auto-renewal of the subscription but the subscription should still be valid for rest of the subscription period, what state does the `getPurchases` api return?

Will it stay as ACTIVE, or will it be changed to CANCELLED?

Answer (score 0):

Found this on the [Cancelling Subscriptions](https://support.google.com/payments/merchant/answer/3094698?hl=en) page.

When canceling subscriptions, remember:

1.No future orders will be charged on that subscription.

2.A 'Cancelled' order status will display on the order details page.

3.Once as subscription is cancelled, it cannot be restated.

4.Google Payments will send a cancellation notification email to the buyer indicating that their subscription has been cancelled.

Try to read more on [webstore payments IAP docs](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/payments-iap)

```
google.payments.inapp.getPurchases
```

> This function will always return the most up to date information, and
>   will reflect if the purchase was cancelled by the user, or refunded
>   through the Payments Merchant console.

Comment: So it's basically saying that getPurchases method will return CANCELED instead of ACTIVE once subscription is canceled. However this conflicts with what I see when I actually tested it. It always returns ACTIVE even after I've cancelled the subscription.

Comment: Yes. The webstore is completely broken. DO NOT USE IT. canceled licences always return ACTIVE, they have zero support for developers, take years (LITERALLY) to fix stuff, and most payments will fail without reason. Here is another pearl of the chrome webstore: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37667802/chrome-extension-in-app-purchase-always-returns-purchase-canceled-even-if-the-p

Answer (score 0):

It will be 'ACTIVE' until the end of the paid period. But if you did refund for a user, the state will change immediately.