# Call to google.payments.inapp.buy returns failure, but item IS purchased in Chrome Webstore

Tags: google-chrome-extension, in-app-purchase, chrome-web-store

In my Chrome extension, when purchasing an in-app item using the Google Payments, the failure handler is invoked instead of the success handler. However, from what I can tell the purchase has been succesful, and I even receive a receipt from Google.

It's a pretty straightforward call:

```
google.payments.inapp.buy({
        'parameters': {'env': 'prod'},
        'sku': '1_point',
        'success': onPurchase,
        'failure': onPurchaseFail 
    });
```

When checking the purchased items using

```
google.payments.inapp.getPurchases
```

the item that just failed is returned. In addition , I can consume it using

```
google.payments.inapp.consumePurchase
```

Has anyone else seen this? Should I just ignore the error?

Thanks,

Edwin.

Comment: Follow the full payments-iap implementation indicated in [In-App Payments with Payments Merchant Account and the Chrome Web Store API](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/payments-iap) and also use the sample code provided in [managed-in-app-payments](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/managed-in-app-payments)

Comment: Thanks but the code is fine. I just found this issue has been reported before on SO : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37667802/chrome-extension-in-app-purchase-always-returns-purchase-canceled-even-if-the-p

Comment: This happens to me as well, I published to trust testers as I don't want to be charged but at the end it charged me! For other people that come to this issue, just call `getPurchases` after finish with `buy` API to confirm that user actually bought the item and follow with relevant logic `My workaround to this problem is to send out a getPurchases api call in the failure handler for the original buy call. -Polly`