# How to test Chrome Extension purchases without publishing?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I added product in "In-app Products" in Chrome Developer Dashboard. Now I'm trying to integrate in-app purchase in the code for the extension and attempting to test it out locally using "Load unpacked extension".

I'm trying to test `google.payments.inapp.getSkuDetails` with something like this

```
google.payments.inapp.getSkuDetails({
   parameters: { env: "prod" },
   success: onDoit,
   failure: onFail
});
```

I get the following response `INVALID_RESPONSE_ERROR`.

Is there a way to get all available products without publishing extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docs states in [Testing purchases](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/payments-iap#testing) that this is only done through publishing the app:

> Prior to publishing your app to the world, you can test the In-App
>   Payment experience by publishing it only to trusted testers. When your
>   app is published to trusted testers, the purchase flow will proceed
>   normally, except they will not be charged.

With regard to your `INVALID_RESPONSE_ERROR` error, this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34999782/chrome-webstore-extension-in-app-purchase-internal-server-error) states that

> Make sure to use the originalId(nmmhkkegccagdldgiimedpiccmgmieda)
>   while calling chrome.runtime.connect() in buy.js, if not then it is
>   the place where it triggers INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.